# cannot read using read() function in C

Tags: c

I have written the following code for reading from "file.dat" using the read function

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int fd,xr;
  char b;
  if ((fd=open("file.dat"))==-1)
  {
    puts("Cannot open file");
    exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
    puts("File opened successfully");
  }
  puts("Trying to read");
  do
  {
    xr = read(fd,b,1);
    printf("%s",b);
  } while(xr!=-1)
  close(fd);
}
```

The file file.dat contains the string "hello" but i am getting some junk characters as output. What is the error?

Comment: printf("%c",b);
 try this ..... otherwise try this char b[1];

Comment: This code has is so poorly written that it's hard to know where to start.  See one of the many posted examples you'll find with Google 'C read example'.  Here's just one for starters:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1103327

Comment: Manoj do indent your code first

Comment: You also need to pass the open flags in the second parameter to `open()`, e.g. `open("file.dat", O_RDONLY)`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Pass address of `b` to `read()` as `xr = read(fd,&b,1);`
2. Use `%c` instead of `%s` to print: `printf("%c",b);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `printf()` format says that you are trying to print a string, which requires that you provide `printf()` with a pointer to a character (the sequence of characters is espected to be null-terminated). However, you're providing only a single character to `printf()`, which it is then treating as if it is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
printf("%c",b);
```

instead of

```
printf("%s",b);
```

because %s expects that you are passing a null terminated char array (aka C-string)

Answer (score 0):

You are giving printf a character but specifying you want to print a string. So, it prints all the bytes starting at b until it hits a terminating null \0, which presumably is your "junk"

Answer (score 0):

1. Try :
   *printf("%c",b); *, because you read a char in do-while{}
2. And Pass address of b to read() as xr = read(fd,&b,1);